# Can ABI be uploaded to Etherscan without source code?

Tags: etherscan, abi

Is it possible to only upload a contracts ABI without including the source code? If so, how?

Curious if Etherscan can still be used to interact with the smart contract, but not make the source code visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered this. Etherscan recommends it for debugging purposes, but it's possible.

https://info.etherscan.com/custom-abi/

Comment: You can upload an ABI and interact with your contract through it, but only if you are logged in with your personal Etherscan account. You cannot “publish” the ABI to the world. Otherwise you could try and scam people by naming a malicious function as `innocentFunction()`. So since Etherscan cannot vouch for you not trying to misrepresent your function’s behaviour with an innocent name, it doesn’t let you publish the ABI in the first place.

Comment: @dwardu But there closed source contracts with only the abi on Etherscan. How about them?

Comment: @user2284570 May you provide the link to one example please?

Answer (score 0):

No. 
To verify your contract you need the exact bytecode. That can only be deduced from the source code and the input parameters used to deploy the contract

Comment: But there closed source contracts with only the abi on Etherscan. How about them?

Comment: I saw that and I wonder the same thing... Kinda breaks the whole concept behind verifying contracts.